# Two IP addresses on two physical interfaces both with gateway

Tags: linux, networking

I have a server that I needs to change its IP address. For DNS propagation I need to have both new and old IP addresses on the server for a little while (72 hours). But when ever I *ifup eth1* (NIC with new IP) the old IP will lose connection to the world (I cannot even ping it).
Both IPs have their own Gateway.
I just did it on windows 2008 without any problem and both IPs work, but on my Linux server I failed because of my lake of knowledge.

The Server has CentOS 6.2

Comment: Why do both IPs have their own gateway? There should be some router that has the machine's connection to the Internet, right? If these two IPs are from two different providers, then you need source-based routing will have to configure it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Read it - he is supposedly switching providers and want all requests to the old IP to go back to the old provider, while all requests to the new IP should have the packets returning to the new provider.

Comment: @TomTom: I don't see any mention of switching providers or multiple providers. Where are you getting that from? If he is, then he needs source-based routing (policy routing). Otherwise, his provider will drop his packets based on their source.

Comment: I'm changing the **transmission provider** and I have two fiber one for each subnet and _I don't have any router_.

Comment: @TomTom is completely right.

Comment: Then you need policy routing. Each provider's router will drop packets that have the IP address assigned to you by the other provider as their source address. You need your own administrative policy to respect their administrative policy.

Comment: I add another IP from NEW IP pool and for working properly I set it to $ip11 and ran: `echo "from $ip11 table New_IPS" >> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-eth1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set up source base routing.

If your 2 IPs are ip0 and ip1 with routes gw0 and gw1: when a connection is made to ip0, you want to route it via gw0; and when it is made on ip1, via gw0.  Your default route will be either via gw0 and gw1, depending on which gateway you want your traffic to go for connection initiated by your server.

I cannot test it, but from [this blog post](http://sysadminsjourney.com/content/2009/04/15/doing-simple-source-policy-routing-centos/), it seams that you need to:

- Create 2 new routing tables:

Use those 2 commands:

```
echo -e "100\tOld_IPS" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
echo -e "200\tNew_IPS" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

- Add routing rules to those tables:

Use those 2 commands, changing your IPs:

```
echo "default table Old_IPS via $gw0" >> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0
echo "default table New_IPS via $gw1" >> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1
```

- Add the source routing for each table:

Use those 2 commands, changing your IPs:

```
echo "from $ip0 table Old_IPS" >> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-eth0
echo "from $ip1 table New_IPS" >> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-eth1
```

Then restart your network using `/etc/init.d/network restart` (be careful not to cut yourself access to your server).

Once you are happy with the setting, you can change your default gateway from gw0 to gw1.